# Vscode is not showing Problems tab in panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i open up vscode in the panel, PROBLEMS tab is missing. I tried uninstalling/purging vscode (including it's config and extensions) and still the same problem.
[image]

Comment: try `Reset View locations` command

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by purging every vscode directory and file, restarting computer and then downloading the vscode .dpkg file from their official website (i didn't use apt-get, or snap). Something like this: https://dzone.com/articles/install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-1804

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple just go on 'View' section at top and select 'Problems' or  press 'Ctrl + Shift + M' and it will get added automatically and if still doesn't work then on left panel there is 'Extension' tab below that will be 'Problems' Tab (which is not in your Screenshot means first opiton should work) just drag it to the Terminal Panel.